# Ng-show: shows empty div but it's not

Tags: angularjs

I have working plunker with my `accordion`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Qk4AxzXLuDDAAXt3wZ6z?p=preview

Did the same in my project and when I click to the accordion header, it shows accordion content but its height is `1px` and data successfully binds.
What's wrong? :(

(it's not a problem with angular and bootstrap version)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the CSS on your own. Refer following dummy CSS for your purpose:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #777;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 16pt;
}
```

where #accordian is id of the div.

Comment: I don't use ui bootstrap because my pagination will break. If you didn't mean ui bootstrap I don't understand you.